# I want the "+" (plus) sign not to be surrounded by whitespace

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Which command lets me change all instances of `+` to `{+}`?

Because using `{+}` there is no whitespace before and after the symbol.

Comment: Are you actually putting the + in braces?  Simple solution, don't do that.  Alternative, {\strut+\strut}.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why shouldn't you want spaces around `+`?

Comment: For me version without spaces looks better. Why shouldn't I use {+} ? Why it is not correct?

Comment: The spacing has been carefully chosen to fit traditional mathematical typographical practice.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that if you don't want whitespace around `+` (plus) symbols, you also do not want whitespace around `-` (minus) symbols. For that matter, you probably don't want whitespace surrounding *any* binary operator, not just `+` and `-` symbols, right? If these assumptions apply, you should execute the instruction

```
\setlength{\medmuskip}{0mu}
```

in the preamble.

That said, I can't recommend doing this -- unless, of course, one deliberately wants to create a poor-looking document. But then, why even bother using TeX and LaTeX?!

---

An MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$u+v-w$

\setlength\medmuskip{0mu} % normally, one would place such an instruction in the preamble
$u+v-w$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do I have to add some package to this solution? Because I have an error

Comment: @JonasAl-Hadad - And *what* would that error be? Definitely no need to add some package.

Comment: "That said, I can't recommend doing this" -> Actually, I just ran across wanting to do this for a legitimate reason, namely to distinguish between strings of symbols that have a plus symbol, and actual addition.  (I guess I could use tt but that might be confusing in a different way to my students, given my previous conventions in class.)